# How to list all Wine window handles which belong to the selected window PID?

Tags: shell, wine

I've the following `winedbg` command which gives me list of all window handles:

```
$ winedbg --command "info wnd"
Window handle        Class Name        Style    WndProc  Thread   Text
00010020             #32769            96000000 00000000 00000022 -- Empty --
 006c02e4            tooltips_class32  84800000 00000000 00000115 -- Empty --
 00270280            tooltips_class32  84800001 00000000 00000115 -- Empty --
 002101a6            tooltips_class32  84800001 00000000 000000d6 -- Empty --
 001700c4            tooltips_class32  84800000 00000000 000000d6 -- Empty --
 019a02ca            ComboLBox         44808041 00000000 00000115 -- Empty --
 00700040            tooltips_class32  94800000 00000000 000000d6 -- Empty --
 004106c8            tooltips_class32  84800001 00000000 00000115 -- Empty --
 008f0172            tooltips_class32  84800000 00000000 00000115 -- Empty --
 007402a8            ComboLBox         44808041 00000000 00000115 -- Empty --
 003807de            MetaQuotes::MetaT 14cf8000 00000000 00000115 1809640: MetaT
  00230782           msctls_statusbar3 5400014e 00000000 00000115 -- Empty --
  000f0670           AfxControlBar140s 56002800 00000000 00000115 Standard
   003b065a          Static            50000100 00000000 00000115 -- Empty --
   00110678          ToolbarWindow32   5400186e 00000000 00000115 Timeframes
   0050069a          ToolbarWindow32   5400186e 00000000 00000115 Line Studies
   001f06ac          ToolbarWindow32   5400186e 00000000 00000115 Charts
   001706b2          ToolbarWindow32   5400186e 00000000 00000115 Standard
  001d05e2           AfxControlBar140s 56008200 00000000 00000115 Tester
   001a048e          Afx:00400000:b:00 56000000 00000000 00000115 Terminal
      002c0118       Shell Embedding   56010000 00000000 00000115 Shell Embeddin
 00900386            nsAppShell:EventW 04c00000 00000000 00000115 nsAppShell:Eve
 07bf01c4            nsAppShell:EventW 04c00000 00000000 000000d6 nsAppShell:Eve
```

I'd like to filter that list to consist only window handles which belong to the specific process (`terminal.exe`/`000000ce`), but the problem is that above list doesn't have list of pids (so I could `grep` it) and my process has 33 different threads:

```
$ winedbg --command "info proc"
 pid      threads  executable (all id:s are in hex)
 000000ce 33       'terminal.exe'
 0000002b 8        'rpcss.exe'
 00000021 4        'explorer.exe'
 0000000e 5        'services.exe'
 0000001a 3        \_ 'plugplay.exe'
 00000012 4        \_ 'winedevice.exe'
```

The available treads can be listed by (removed some for readability):

```
$ winedbg --command "info thread"
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    0000011a    0
    0000001d    0
    00000014    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
000000ce terminal.exe
    000000de    0
    0000013a    0
    0000004f    0
    00000115    0
```

What would be the easiest way to filter the list of window handles to consist only these which belong to the specific process?

Is there any special option which I'm not aware of, or I need to have few line parsing script for that to match pid->thread->wnd ids and `grep` it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the command listing the selected handles (replace `terminal.exe` with the app name):

> `$ winedbg --command "info wnd" | grep -wf <(winedbg --command "info threads" | ex +"/terminal.exe\n\zs/;,/^\S/-p" -scq! /dev/stdin | awk '{print $1}' )`

Basically we're `grep`ing the list of all window handlers (`info wnd`) by specific list of threads. The list is parsed by `ex` editor based on the `info threads` output and saved into a special file (`/dev/fd`) which is loaded by `grep` (`-f`). Awk command is used to print the first column where the thread ids are listed.

Explanation of used `ex` syntax:

- `+"cmd"` - run the command
- `/terminal.exe\n\zs/;,/^\S/-p`

  - `/pattern1/;,/pattern2/` - a range search (`;` places the cursor after first pattern)
  - `/terminal.exe\n\zs/` - search for `terminal.exe` and mark the starting point (`\zs`)
  - `/^\S/` - selection ends at the first non-blank line
  - `-p` - prints the above selection, minus one line (related [post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/10677/467))
  - `-scq!` - **s**ilently and forcibly (`!`) execute the **q**uit **c**ommand
  - `/dev/stdin` - read the content from the standard input